# Verificação com IF e INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

Galera tenho essas consultas no banco de dados

```
<?php 
    $consulta = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mesas LIMIT 50");
    if (mysql_num_rows($consulta)==true) {
       while($lnmesas = mysql_fetch_array($consulta)){ 
       $consultainterna = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM mesas INNER JOIN pedidos");
?>
```

Eu preciso fazer uma comparação de um registro no banco de dados em que a coluna `mesas` da tabela `pedidos` seja igual a coluna `id` da tabela `mesas`. Caso o resultado seja positivo ele dê um `echo` com um valor, senão ele dê um `echo` com outro valor.

Eu peinsei que dessa forma funcionaria:

```
if($lnmesas['pedidos.mesas'] == $lnmesas['mesas.id']){
    echo "success":
}else{
    echo "danger";
}
```

Mas infelizmente não funcionou. Alguém pode me explicar qual a forma correta de fazer isso, sou iniciante, não tenho muita experiência ainda.

aqui esta a estrutura das minhas tabelas...
[image: tabela pedidos]

[image: tabela mesas]

Comment: Qual tabela é qual ai rsss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente usar o on do MYSQL, segue abaixo um exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM mesas m LEFT JOIN pedidos p ON p.mesas = m.id
```

> Depois somente faça a verificação com o PHP

```
<?php

     $consulta = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mesas m LEFT JOIN pedidos p ON p.mesas = m.id LIMIT 50") or die (mysql_error());

     while($dados = mysql_fetch_assoc($consulta)) {
          if(!empty($dados['p.id'])) {
              echo "success";
          } else {
              echo "danger";
          }
     }
```

> Considere também estudar o USO do PDO, o MySQL_* já é uma função obsoleta do php.

Comment: Estou com os dois projetos, esse, e o outro de estudo mysqli_*, obrigado pela dica e pela resposta.

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Comment: @AlfredoLima é alguma coluna na query que esta com problema, copia ela e roda no seu PHP My Admin ou WorkBench. Ai pega o erro e me passa aqui.

Comment: Adicionei um tratamento de erro. no código.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, você deveria postar o schema do teu banco de dados.

Mas vamos lá. Supondo que no teu banco de dados `pedidos.mesas` e `mesas.id` sejam do
mesmo tipo, então faríamos:

```
SELECT IF(
          /*Condição, se não for NULL é porque há pedido*/
          NOT ISNULL(p.mesas),

          /*Se verdadeiro retornará 'success'*/
          'success',

          /*Se falso retornará 'danger'*/
          'danger'
         ) as retorno_coluna,
  m.*, /*Também retorna as colunas da tabela mesas*/
  p.*  /*Também retorna as colunas da tabela pedidos*/
FROM mesas m
/*Left Join, visto que você quer recuperar
  a lista de mesas independente do pedido*/
LEFT JOIN pedidos p ON m.id = p.mesas
```

Bom a consulta acima deve funcionar. Mas se acaso, houver colunas com os mesmos nomes em ambas tabelas, você, ao invés de retornar `p.*` e `m.*`, deverá retornar por nome cada coluna que você precisará.
Veja o resultado no phpMyAdmin:
[image: phpMyAdmin]

Então juntando tudo com PHP fica assim:

```
    <?php
        $consulta = mysql_query("SELECT IF(NOT ISNULL(p.mesas), 'success', 'danger') as retorno_coluna, m.*, p.* FROM mesas m LEFT JOIN pedidos p ON m.id = p.mesas");
        if (mysql_num_rows($consulta)==true)
          {
            while($lnmesas = mysql_fetch_array($consulta))
              {?>         
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-2">
          <div class="ls-box">
          <div class="ls-alert-<?php echo $lnmesas['retorno_coluna']; ?>">
            <h6 class="ls-title-1"><?php  echo $lnmesas['retorno_coluna']; ?></h6>
              <strong><?php echo $lnmesas['id']  ?></strong>
          </div>
        <a href="index.php?mod=info-mesa&mesaid=<?php echo $lnmesas['id'] ?>">
          <button class="ls-btn-primary ls-ico-cog">Gerenciar Mesa</button><a>  
          </div>
        </div><?php
               }
          }
        else
          {?>
       <center>
       <div class="ls-alert-warning"><strong>OPS! </strong> Não existe nenhuma mesa com pedidos, cheque se você realmente lançou seu pedido clicando na aba pedidos aqui do lado</div>
       </center><?php
          }
    ?>
```

Comment: syntax error, unexpected 'IF' (T_IF) in ....... on line 23
23>> <?php SELECT IF(

ele retornou esse erro

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta e coloquei a estrutura das minhas tabelas pra ver se te ajuda com a resposta, muito obrigado des de já.

Comment: @AlfredoLima, posta o teu código PHP, pois eu testei a query acima e funcionou no phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Acho que entendi o que aconteceu.
Faça o seguinte @AlfredoLima coloque a Query dentro de 
$consulta = mysql_query("AQUI DENTRO");

Comment: olha meu codigo é esse aqui

http://pastebin.com/KyGv0J8Z
na linha 9 e na linha 10 é onde eu preciso fazer a if

Comment: pelo que entendi no seu codigo existe o valor danger no seu db
e no meu não existe, vou dar outro exemplo...... eu quero é alterar a class de uma div exemplo:

<div class'ls-alert-<?php aqui dentro a if que exibe o danger ou success ?>"> </div>

Comment: Não @AlfredoLima, não existe valor danger. Basei-me em teu código inicial onde você printa success ou danger a depender do resultado.
Então a query faz o teste e já trás o resultado dentro da coluna 'retorno_coluna'.
Se houver alguma coisa que você não compreendeu no código PHP acima e na query do MYSQL explica aí a tua dúvida.

Comment: è porque eu fiz o codigo exatamente igual ao seu, cheguei a copiar  o codigo pra ver se eu n tinha digitado alguma coisa errada e mesmo assim ele imprime o mesmo erro 
Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xamp\htdocs\projects\MOClient 2.0\modulos\mesas\mesas.php on line 17
e na linha 17 ele tem esse codigo

 if (mysql_num_rows($consulta)==true)